# Number of combinations with some repetition

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Imagine that I have a group with elements {A,A,B,C,D} and I want to generate all non-ordenated possible combinantions with 2 letters. They are {A,A}, {A,B}, {A,C}, {A,D}, {B,C}, {B,D} and {C,D}.

Is it possible to calculte this number in general (a group of $k$ elements: $n_1$ elements $A_1$, $n_2$ elements $A_2$ ... with $\sum n_i=k$)?

I guess it will be something related with combinatorics numbers. However, I can't figure out a general formula.

My specific case is groups of 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 elements from group {A,A,A,A,B,B,C,D,E}

Comment: Note:  "group" has a precise meaning in mathematics, here you just mean "collection" or "multiset".  Also, I suspect you meant "unordered" when you wrote "non-ordenated".

Comment: The answer you want is, in general, going to depend on some arithmetic between the total number of desired elements and the $n_i$.  Best, perhaps, to work recursively:  For each possible number of $A_k$, you can build the rest of your multiset recursively from a smaller multiset.

Comment: Consider the use of generating functions.  For your specific case, consider the function $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2)(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)$, [expanding that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand+%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%29%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%29%281%2Bx%29%281%2Bx%29%281%2Bx%29), and looking at the coefficient of the corresponding term, for instance the expansion here has $23x^5$ so there are $23$ size five "combinations" available to you.

Comment: @JMoravitz So elegant, that I deleted my comments.